# How to use msgbox in R

Tags: r, user-interaction, msg, msgbox

How can I display a message box in `R` ?

I'm looking for something similar to `msgbox` in VBA, so I can for example alert the user about a problem.

Additionally I would like to allow some user interaction. So for example I could ask the user what day the program should use.

Comment: Can you ask your question so that it will be more specific so it doesn't get closed? That being said, are you looking for this? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tcltk2/index.html

Comment: Package svDialogs has some higher level functions that tap into tcltk mentioned by Roman and ialm.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly that what I was looking for. Sorry I didn't specify too much. I thought it was ok the way I wrote. I'll make sure that doesn't happen again

Comment: I think the question should be reopened, it has a lot of views and asks about a legit R feature, I reworded it and asked to reopen.

Answer (score 19):

What do you want to do exactly? Two things come to mind.

You can use the `tcl/tk` package in R to create a UI. See some examples with code from here: http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/tcltk/. This package provides quick and easy functions to create message boxes, widgets, and other simple or complicated UIs. I created a point and click pipeline for producing plots in R using this package a couple years ago for users that were unfamiliar with R. I believe that this package is already installed with newer versions of R.

Here is a very simple example you can try:

```
require(tcltk)
msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "Title of message box",
                       message = "Hello, world!", icon = "info", type = "ok")
```

[image]

You can also create message boxes that accept inputs from the user that you can use later, etc. Check out the website I linked for a list of examples to get you started.

Next, we have the newer Shiny interface, which can ask for user input and produce output dynamically over the web, though it is a little more advanced. It provides a user interface through your browser through some simple R code, and the backend is created using R code as well. No javascript or html is required to get a simple set up going, but there is a slight learning curve for coding the Shiny app. You can easily create local Shiny apps by simply installing the `shiny` package on your local machine, but some set up is required to set up a server to deploy your R app outside of your local system. The RStudio team is offering free accounts on their servers if you want to deploy your R Shiny app over the web. Go to http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/ for some examples, and you can find tutorials at http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with `tkmessageBox`, I don't see any box (but there's the red button on RStudio that shows that something is runnin)