# MessageBox in R

Tags: r, rstudio, tcltk

I would like to create a messagebox using R. A short [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794700/how-to-use-msgbox-in-r) suggested the `tcltk` package. The `tcltk::tk_messageBox()` command actually worked the first time I tried it.

However, I then I updated to Windows 10, switched to R 3.4.3, using RStudio v1.1.423. Now the same command does not work, actually terminating the R Session. A [second research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729394/rstudio-specific-issue-with-the-tcltk-package) showed that this is indeed an issue other users have experienced as well.

So, here is my question: Is there either a way to resolve the compatibility issue of the `tcltk` library and R/RStudio? Alternatively, is there another package that could produce the same result? (I would like to avoid going as far as `shiny`, that has been suggested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Windows 7, R 3.4.3 and RStudio 1.1.423 I have a similar problem, it looks like RStudio hangs, but in fact, the *message-box has popped up, just that it does not become the active window* and I have to minimize RStudio to see it.

The command I am running is:

```
tcltk::tk_messageBox(caption = "Hi", message = "what?", icon = "info", type = "yesno")
```

Comment: Ouch! All this time it was running in the background? Now I feel stupid. It does lose its functionality a bit though if I have to minimize RStudio every time. Is there no way to bring it in the background (even using some R command?)

Comment: Looks difficult using R, because once it pops up, it's waiting to process your reply first, whereas I cannot find an argument that can be passed to `tk_messageBox` in order to specify that it should get the focus

Comment: I guess that does it. Thank you for your reply! Please feel free to update if you find out anything new.