# Is there really no proper R message box functionality out there?

Tags: r, windows, shiny, dialog, messagebox

I am developing an R Shiny application on Windows 7 and would like it to communicate with the user in some ways, primarily outputting some optimization results in the form of a message box.

I tried `winDialog()` function first but it seems to have only three parameters, thus it's not really customizable. I would have wanted to at least give a proper title for the appearing message box instead of the basic Information title but there doesn't seem to be such an argument. Furthermore, I also dislike `winDialog()` for being totally platform dependent; if possible, I'd stick to functionalities that won't crash if I give the app to someone using an Apple product...

Then I tried using the `tkmessagebox()` function from `tcltk` package but sadly every time the message box appears *behind* the running app, which first gave me the impression of my app suddenly freezing until I eventually found the message box is hidden behind the app. This is very-very impractical for the user, having to minimize the app window every time, so this didn't solve my issue either.

```
winDialog(type ="ok", message = paste("Initial profit value is: ", toString(MAX_PROFIT)) )

library(tcltk)
tkmessageBox(title = "Initial profit calculation", message = toString(MAX_PROFIT), icon = "info", type = "ok")
```

I also came across a thread from last year here on StackOverflow, mentioning the exact same problem with the `tkmessageBox` function (you can find that thread here: [MessageBox in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008964/messagebox-in-r)). Apparently, there doesn't seem to be any straightforward solution for the disappearing R message boxes, or at least I haven't found any information as of now.

Comment: Depending on what you really want to display in the box, perhaps `shinyWidgets`' sweet alert with HTML could be an option. See: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets

Comment: 1) Use shiny native https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/notifications.html
2) I personally like https://github.com/MangoTheCat/shinytoastr

Answer (score -1):

I use shinyalert package. It works well and does exactly what is required. Here's a neat link: https://deanattali.com/blog/shinyalert-package/

Also, there's a modalDialog box option. This appears like the message box in your browser that asks to allow to send notifications to you.
Link: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html